# .net application remote server best solution

Tags: .net, vb.net, networking, server

I am developing an application in vb.net. Right now I am connected on a shared folder under my local network that works as a server for the application sharing updates, settings files and other resources sometimes >25Gb. since the application will work on many clients not under the same network I am figuring out a way to replace my shared folder with a remote server.

1. i have considered using a cloud service API like onedrive or googleDrive but there are limitations in terms of speed and data size (i.e onedrive API allows <25GB file transfers) and the code will be much more complicated and prone to errors.
2. installing a vpn on every client is not possible.
3. I came to the conclusion that the best possible solution would be to access on each client a onedrive account and syncronyze the `serverFolder` in order to use it as a normal folder on the HDD. One drive will then take care to sync the files on the cloud when there is internet connection.

I am looking for other suggestions

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but seems like you're trying to re-invent the wheel here.  There are already many solutions out there for deploying and updating software packages such as ClickOnce that might be worth investigating.